# How to measure voltage with a floating supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-measurement, voltage-reference

In the example below, ground of a dual supply is referenced to **+Vout**.

Assuming we have a MCU connected to **VCC** and **+Vout**, if we then try to measure the voltage at **+Vout** with the ADC, we're basically measuring the ground of MCU.

The actual measurement should be the voltage between **+Vout** and **-Vout**, which we can assume to have the maximum value of 20V.

[image]

- How do you measure the floating voltage in this situation?

Comment: You can go with galvanic isolation of one sort another (one of which includes floating the ADC), re-bias the signal, or you can go with dividers and difference amplifiers:  https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/high-voltage-differential-probe/ but most will require a floating or negative supply.

Comment: What is a blow ground? What does MCU mean?

Comment: @Uwe Below*, MCU; Micro Controller Unit.

Comment: I don't see there any micro controller unit.

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't want to add another power source to the circuit, can't it be done the existing power sources?

Comment: You may be surprised but no one ever wants to add another supply. Unless you feel like using a relay or optos to float a sample cap back and forth.

Comment: @Uwe The MCU doesn't matter in this example, all that matter is the power supplied to the MCU which I already described.

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry but the article that you linked isn't helpful.

Comment: The link just describes the method using difference amplifiers.

Comment: @DKNguyen I know how to use a dif-amp, I just don't know how to implant it in this example.

Comment: Then that means you you don't know enough to use the diff amp in this example, in which case read the link, but as I said, it does require more supplies. There aren't any easy shortcuts here. I know it seems like a pain in the ass just to measure a voltage.

Comment: You don't want to measure **+Vout**, because it is the 0V of the MCU, as you said. You want to measure the voltage between **+Vout** and **-Vout**, so actually you want to measure **-Vout**. Correct? If it is, what is the most negative value of **-Vout**?

Comment: @ElectronSurf I'm saying your desire to not use another supply is the norm, yet another supply always ends up being used anyways. It is obviously not because we want to. If there was a simpler way, you can be sure as hell we would all being using it.

Comment: @devnull Yes I want to measure the voltage difference between +Vout and -Vout, The most negative value of -Vout? what do you mean?

Comment: What is the largest expected value of the voltage between +Vout and -Vout?

Comment: @devnull It's let's say 20V.

Comment: There are analog opto isolators which don't require a separate supply but they are even more complicated

Comment: If you can trust the 0V reference for measurement (e.g. low current), its doable with a simple inverting amplifier connected to **-Vout** with the module of the gain less than one (to get +5V from -20V, you need a -1/4 gain, for example). For better accuracy it is better to use a differential amplifier, as mentioned in the above comments, so you can connect it directly to the load (and avoid measuring the voltage drop in the wires.).

Comment: @devnull A differential amplifier with non-inverting input connected to +Vout and -Vout and inverting input connected to -Vout and op amp output? how does this even work? can you please elaborate a bit with an answer?

Comment: @devnull I'm unable to get any value in the simulator, not with inverting amplifier and not with dif-amp.

Comment: I've tried to explain in an answer and I've also moved some information you provided to the question.

Comment: I see that you are using my drawing. That's fine. And to solve the issue with GND and ADC measurement, all you need is an inverting amplifier with a gain of less than one. As devnull has shown you. Or add another separate floating supply just for the voltmeter uC.

Comment: @G36 Is this yours? I found it from google! [I can't make it work though](https://tinyurl.com/2yvlbhol), is it because of the simulator?

Comment: See here https://tinyurl.com/223757u8 (only voltage regulation part)

Comment: @G36 Your equations on this drawing is really helpful, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: This was the reason I made this drawing in the first place. I simply wanted to show and explain how this most widely used topology of a lab power supply works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the voltage being measured is not floating, but only negative with respect to the ADC, these are the 2 simpler options I can think of.

If you can trust the 0V reference for measurement (e.g. low current), it is doable with a simple inverting amplifier connected to **-Vout** with the module of the gain less than one.

Below I've assumed you can use the voltage reference in you circuit also as the ADC reference and I've also assumed it is 1.25V (modify the resistors otherwise): the gain is \$-\frac{5k}{80k}=\frac{1.25}{-20}\$.

[image]

No accuracy requirements were mentioned and we also don't know the load current. You can have considerable error with the circuit above by assuming that +Vout is 0V (with respect to the ADC) at the load. To avoid this, you could use a differential amplifier (which brings other problems, like resistor mismatch).

[image]

Both circuits have the same simulated output since wire resistance is zero: 1.25V for -20V at **-Vout** and 0V for 0V  at **-Vout**.

[image]

Comment: How did you power the op amps in the simulator? are they powered from VCC and VEE supplies in the question?

Comment: Which opamp model are you using? The decision on how to power them depends on this, on their output range for the ADC and the values of the voltage rails you have.

Comment: I was using the wrong simulator, thank you.